# If $y=x^6$ has only one real root,then does that mean it has an odd number (5) complex roots??

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I read that complex roots always exists in pairs.But, the equation $y=x^6$ has only $1$ real root.Does that mean that it has $5$ complex roots

Comment: It has a real root of multiplicity.

Comment: What you have read is either wrong or you have misread it. The collection of roots is a multiset, not a set, and $0$ is a root which occurs in multiplicity $6.$

Comment: I think when he said "I read that complex roots always exists in pairs". He was referring to the Complex Conjugate Theorem, then he was just applying it to his own example. So what is read was right, it's just his application was misguided.

Answer (score 2):

The function has no complex roots. The only root is $x=0$ and it is a repeated root.

Answer (score 2):

No,
Actually in $y=x⁶$ even though it looks like there is only one real root $x=0$, It has 6 real roots and no complex roots. It just so happens to be the case that all 6 roots coincide.

As an analogy think of the equation $y=x²+2x+1$.
It has only one zero that is $x=-1$ and we say that both of its roots "coincide".